# Como posso alterar o nome da coluna de uma tabela resultante de muitos para muitos no gorm

Tags: relacionamento, golang, gorm

Eu já mexi muito com Nestjs utilizando TypeORM e agora estou aprendendo a mexer com Golang e Gorm.
Eu estou refazendo um sistema em Nestjs para Go e estou passando por um problema na hora de utilizar relações many2many. Como estou trabalhando com um banco já em produção e populado preciso fazer a modelagem das struct`s idêntica ao outro projeto para que não haja problemas.

Tenho duas tabelas que relacionam de forma múltipla, elas são **playlists** e **genres** e no banco em produção elas resultam na tabela **playlists_genres** com os seguintes campos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que os campos estão como **playlistsId** e **genresId**

Já no projeto em Golang o resultado do m2m das tabelas estão resultando em:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que os campos gerados estão divergentes do que eu preciso, preciso que sejam gerados identificas ao do banco em produção, ou seja **playlistsId** e **genresId**.

Meu código de relacionamento está da seguinte forma:

```
type Playlist struct {
    ID        int32     `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:true"`
    Status    bool      `json:"status" gorm:"not null;default:false"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"createdAt" gorm:"column:created_at;autoCreateTime:milli;type:TIMESTAMP without time zone;default:now();not null"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updatedAt" gorm:"column:updated_at;autoUpdateTime:milli;type:TIMESTAMP without time zone;default:now();not null"`

    Genres        []Genre             `json:"genres" gorm:"many2many:playlists_genres"`
}
```

```
type Genre struct {
    ID          int32     `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:true"`
    Name        string    `json:"name" gorm:"not null;type:varchar(255)"`

    Playlists    []Playlist         `json:"playlists" gorm:"many2many:playlists_genres"`
}
```

Já procurei bastante e não encontrei uma forma de mudar o nome dessas colunas a não ser criar manualmente uma tabela intermediária com as colunas com os nomes que eu preciso e relaciona-la de um para muitos.

Poderiam me auxiliar nisto? É possível fazer isso sem a criação de uma tabela manualmente? Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma possível forma de resolver isso é usando uma NamingStrategy customizada para o seu projeto, assim você consegue sobrescrever as configurações padrão do GORM e tratar esse caso específico de forma diferente.

Aqui mostra como pode ser feito: https://gorm.io/docs/gorm_config.html#NamingStrategy

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/42/3774)

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso eu tentaria usar uma struct intermediária para gerar essa tabela de associação. Você usa essa struct na tag do Gorm tanto na struct Playlist quanto na struct Genres:

```
many2many:custom_playlists_genres;




type Playlist struct {
   ID        int32     `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:true"`
   Status    bool      `json:"status" gorm:"not null;default:false"`
   CreatedAt time.Time `json:"createdAt" gorm:"column:created_at;autoCreateTime:milli;type:TIMESTAMP without time zone;default:now();not null"`
   UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updatedAt" gorm:"column:updated_at;autoUpdateTime:milli;type:TIMESTAMP without time zone;default:now();not null"`

   Genres []Genre `json:"genres" gorm:"many2many:custom_playlists_genres;joinForeignKey:playlist_id;joinReferences:genre_id"`
```

}

```
type Genre struct {
   ID        int32     `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:true"`
   Name      string    `json:"name" gorm:"not null;type:varchar(255)"`

   Playlists []Playlist `json:"playlists" gorm:"many2many:custom_playlists_genres;joinForeignKey:genre_id;joinReferences:playlist_id"`
```

}

```
type CustomPlaylistsGenres struct {
   PlaylistID int32 `gorm:"column:playlistId"`
   GenreID    int32 `gorm:"column:genreId"`
```

}

Depois na struct CustomPlaylistGenres você coloca manualmente o nome da coluna.